# how to replace a middle of string in a file in perl language

Tags: regex, perl, perl-data-structures

For Example input file is

```
ID Name Dept_id
1 aaa 1
2 ddd 1
3 sss 2
```

It is  tab separated file

The is output will be like

```
ID Name Dept_id
1 aaa 1.1
2 ddd 2.1
3 sss 3.2
```

Any one can help me??

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -pe's/^(\d+)\s\S+\s\K(\d+)/$1.$2/' input.txt > output.txt
```

In perl code the program would look like so:

```
while (<>) {
    s/^(\d+)\s\S+\s\K(\d+)/$1.$2/;
} continue {
    print;
}
```

The substitution regex looks for a line starting with one or more numbers `\d+`, and capture them with parentheses, followed by a whitespace `\s`, non-whitespaces `\S+`, a whitespace again, and followed by numbers, which we also capture. The `\K` (keep) indicates that we do not wish to change anything to the left. Then we replace it with the first captured string, a period `.` and the second captured string.

Answer (score 2):

You want to add the `ID` number in `dept_id`. So iterate the while loop for the file.

Then remove the newlines using `chomp`.

Then `split` the each line into the array by space or tab separated, afterwards print the array by using array index.

Your `$ar[0]` holds the id. so print with `$ar[0].$ar[2]`

```
open my $handler, "<","file.txt";
my $first = <$handler>;
print "$first";
while (<$handler>)
{
    chomp;
    my @ar = split(/\s+/);
    print "$ar[0]\t$ar[1]\t$ar[0].$ar[2]\n";

}
```

Or simply try this one liner

`-n` for loop over the input file.  Then `$.` tells the current line number.

Then here i used pattern matching for your case.

I created the temporary list named  `$on $tw $th`. `$on` holds the id, `$tw` holds the Name, `$th` holds the Dept_id. Then it will give by the printing  `"$on\t$tw\t$on.$th"`

```
perl -ne 'if($. == 1){ print "$_"; next;} ($on,$tw,$th)= $_ =~m/(\w+)/g; print "$on\t$tw\t$on.$th\n";' file.txt
```